# I encounter an error in the ISR function when using the code specified in this community for arduinodue to act as a slave in spi communication

Tags: serial, spi, arduino-due

```
#include<SPI.h>

volatile boolean received;
volatile byte receivedData;

ISR (SPI_STC_vect)        //Inerrrput routine function 
{
  receivedData = SPDR;   // Get the received data from SPDR register
  received = true;       // Sets received as True 
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(MISO,OUTPUT);   //Sets MISO as OUTPUT
  SPCR |= _BV(SPE);       //Turn on SPI in Slave Mode
  received = false;
  SPI.attachInterrupt();  //Activate SPI Interuupt 
}


void loop()
{ 
  if(received) {                        
    SPDR = receivedData;    // send back the received data, this is not necessary, only for demo purpose
    received = false;
    Serial.print(receivedData, HEX);
  }
}
```

the compiler gives an error with isr specified

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @JRobert It's quite encrypted, but he mentioned "arduinodue" so I suspect Arduino DUE (with completely different MCU) :D

Answer (score 1):

This program seems to have been written for an AVR-based Arduino, like a
classic Uno or Nano. The registers `SPCR` and `SPDR`, the bit `SPE` on
`SPCR`, and the `SPI_STC` interrupt, are all documented on the
ATmega328P’s datasheet.

Yours is an Arduino Due, which uses a completely different
microcontroller. AVR-specific code cannot run on the Due.

Comment: There is a code of SPI Slave for DUE at https://forum.arduino.cc/t/arduino-due-spi-interrupt/574857/3.